# Cannot install published app with clickonce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, clickonce, publishing

I am having problem with installing app that I have published into FTP server, target framework which is selected is 4.6. This is windows forms project type. While I'am launching setup.exe file which is in Debug/app.publish folder I am reciving error: "An error occurred trying to download". This is my error code from install.log file:

> The following properties have been set: Property: [AdminUser] = true
> {boolean} Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string} Property:
> [NTProductType] = 1 {int} Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64
> {string} Property: [VersionNT] = 10.0.0 {version} Launching
> Application. URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697191'

I already tried to change traget framework version , clear the C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 folder.

Does someone have any suggestion how I can try to solve this issue?

Comment: Invalid SSL Certificate (WinInet)

Comment: You probably want to install from a HTTPS source. You can Publish to a FTP destination.